# Small Oscillations

Tags: oscillators

When a problem asks to consider small oscillations about equilibrium, I know this implies that powers higher than one can be sent to zero, but does this say anything about the velocities? For example, in a problem I was doing, I was told that I could send $x\dot{\phi}^2$ to $0$ because it is a third order term, however we were only told there were small oscillations in $\phi$ and $x$, not that the velocity had to be small, per se. (The scenario I had in mind was a spring with a high spring coefficient oscillating very rapidly near equilibrium.)
Why can we ignore higher order terms in velocities?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The small angle approximation is usually introduced to simplify the equations of motion of a system which has a sinusoidal dependence on one on its degrees of freedom (like a physical pendulum) thus taking $\sin(x)$ to $x$ and $\cos(x)$ to $1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ by way of the Taylor expansion. Without seeing the problem, it's not clear to me what's going on.

Comment: I didn't have an actual problem in mind (I forget what the one was that I was confused on.) In general, when we are told 'small oscillations' does that only mean $\delta x \rightarrow 0$ or does it also mean $\delta \dot{x} \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Which terms one neglects is a free choice. If you were told to do an analysis neglecting $x\phi^2$, then I would take it and thank the heavens that you didn't have to calculate what happens if one doesn't. Or... if you are interested, make the assumption that it's not small and do the work. It could be quite interesting... or quite frustrating. My feeling is that it's probably the latter and that your teacher was trying to spare you the frustration.